# Why is Grails 2.3.x so Slow?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails, grails-2.0

I compared the execution of

```
grails run-app
```

between Grails 2.2.4 and Grails 2.3.4. It turns out that Grails 2.3.4 is very slow. Even when I started a new project and installed a few plugins like the [gwt plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gwt) Grails 2.3.4 becomes so slow. There is another problem there is only very few command line output. The application comes to the line which says: "COMPILE START" then you have to wait a very long time. You do not get any feedback so you do not know what grails is doing. I liked the Grails 2.2.x series which gives you a lot of feedback.

**What can I do to make Grails 2.3.4 load faster?**

Comment: In Grails 2.3 + if you run your commands from the interactive mode `grails >`, your JVM will stay running, therefore, all your repeated commands will run even faster. [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/interactive.html)

Comment: #confile ..may be one should ask burt ,  ?

Comment: I did notice that I had to bump up the memory settings for the JVM a bit when upgrading to grails 2.3.x. After doing that, things seem to be running quite smoothly for me.